# How to remove duplicate emails in Office 365 OWA?

Tags: email, office-365, outlook-on-the-web

We are using Office 365 and prior to this, we used Gmail. When I was using Gmail I had a filter by which I was moving emails from a particular account to a folder and also keeping a copy in the Inbox.

After the migration to Office 365, the folder where the emails were moved was migrated as well.

Unfortunately, I had forgotten that the filter that I had before was keeping a copy of emails of that folder in Inbox and I created a new Rule in OWA for all future emails to move into this folder and NOT keeping anything in Inbox.

I also have manually moved all the existing emails into that folder, since OWA doesn't support running a rule on existing emails.

After that when I was checking older emails in that folder I have found that there are duplicate emails and then I remember the settings I did when I was using Gmail.

It would be great if I can delete the duplicate emails from this folder.

Manually finding and deleting duplicate emails will take a long time as there are thousands of emails. I know it is possible using Outlook Client, but since I'm a Linux user I don't have the client. Is it possible to achieve what I want in OWA?